# Pre loading backbone collections

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

So what I'm wanting to do is have Backbone fetch all my collections when the router starts, and then keep all the collections and not have to re-fetch and reload all the collections while moving to different routes in the router. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Backbone.js docs:](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch)

> Note that fetch should not be used to populate collections on page
>   load — all models needed at load time should already be [bootstrapped](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap)
>   in to place. fetch is intended for lazily-loading models for
>   interfaces that are not needed immediately: for example, documents
>   with collections of notes that may be toggled open and closed.

This is what I meant in my comment:

```
<script>
  define("data", function() {
    return <?php echo json here ?>;
  });
</script>
```

Then you can have `var data = require("data");` and use it to init Backbone models/collections. I'm not sure this is the right way of doing it.

Comment: How could this be done in an AMD fashion (using require.js) and php instead of rails?

Comment: I don't think that it will be a problem to output json object in inline script with php (I'm doing it in python). If you don't want to have a global variable with data, then you can probably wrap your inline script in requirejs define function call. Just ensure the code that will use the data will be executed after dom is loaded.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I ended up doing, it helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

Well, backbone does this by default. Just add code to your router to create an instance of each collection and call `fetch()` once on each collection. Then make sure the rest of your app just uses those same collection instances and does NOT call `fetch()` on them again. It's really that simple.

However, I presume you want other bits of your application to be able to call `fetch()` and have this silently use cached data if needed. This a considered a hard problem to do correctly, but a naive and simple implementation would be to simply store an `isCached` flag as a property of your collection and check that in your overridden `fetch()` method and just return without doing anything if your collection data is already loaded.